# Root finding with a kinked function using NLsolve in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I am currently trying to solve a complementarity problem  with a function that features a downward discontinuity, using the `mcpsolve()` function of the `NLsolve` package in Julia. The function is reproduced [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i5cx.png) for specific parameters, and the numbers below refer to the three panels of the figure.

Unfortunately, the algorithm does not always return the interior solution, even though it exists:

- In (1), when starting at 0, the algorithm stays at 0, thinking that the boundary constraint binds,
- In (2), when starting at 0, the algorithm stops right before the downward jump, even though the solution lies to the right of this point.

These problems occur regardless of the method used - trust region or Newton's method. Ideally, the algorithm would look for potential solutions in the entire set before stopping.

I was wondering if some of you had worked with similar functions, and had found a clever solution to bypass these issues. Note that

- Starting to the right of the solution would not solve these problems, as they would also occur for other parametrization - see (3) this time,
- It is not known *a priori* where in the parameter space the particular cases occur.

As an illustrative example, consider the following piece of code. Note that the function is smoother, and yet here as well the algorithm cannot find the solution.

```
function f!(x,fvec)
  if x[1] <= 1.8
    fvec[1] = 0.1 * (sin(3*x[1]) - 3)
  else 
    fvec[1] = 0.1 * (x[1]^2 - 7)
  end 
end

NLsolve.mcpsolve(f!,[0.], [Inf], [0.], reformulation = :smooth, autodiff = true)
```

Once more, setting the initial value to something else than 0 would only postpone the problem. Also, as pointed out by Halirutan, `fzero` from the `Roots` package would probably work, but I'd rather use `mcpsolve()` as the problem is initially a complementarity  problem.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `fzero` from the `Roots` package? For a similar function `f(x) = if x<10 exp(0.1x)-5.0 else exp(0.1x)-7.0 end` this gives the desired solution with `fzero(f,0,20)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't because I am actually trying to solve a complementarity problem, and I think the `Roots` package does not provide any algorithm for this. I'll edit my question!

Comment: If possible, maybe you can include a small code example so that everyone has something to try.

Comment: Sure, just edited the question now.

Comment: If the problem is not too large, may be you could use a global solver (e.g. Baron or Couenne), Otherwise a multistart approach with a local MCP solver.

Comment: I opted for the second solution so far, and will have a look at the global solvers, thank you! It remains however that the `mcpsolver()` cannot find the root of a cubic equation..

Comment: FYI, I've asked a related question [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/non-monotonic-equations-and-mcpsolver-from-nlsolve/3493). I'll post the answer below if it is relevant.